# xna sprite to mouse position

Tags: c#, class, matrix

In XNA 4.0 how do I get a sprite to move to the mouses coordinates. I know that this would be possible to do like this:

```
if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) 
{
    Vector2 shipPos = new Vector2(ms.X,ms.Y);
}
```

but because I'm using a camera that follows the ship this does not work properly. The reason for this is that the position of the mouse is relative to the screen and if the ship has been moved to let say (500,500) when I click in the top left corner of the window the ship goes back to (0,0), even tough I want the ship to move from the ships position up towards the corner. Here's the code for my matrix:

```
class Camera
{
    public Matrix transform;
    Viewport view;
    Vector2 centre;

    public Camera(Viewport newView)
    {
        view = newView;
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Game1 ship)
    {
        int w = Game1.width;
        int h = Game1.height;
        centre = new Vector2(ship.FSpos.X - (w / 2 - 189/2), 
                             ship.FSpos.Y - (h / 2-128/2));
        transform = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1, 1, 0)) *
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centre.X, -centre.Y, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, bad use of language :D. I meant that the ship should move from the center(in the example(500,500)) to the position relative to the map which is located in the top left corner. These coordinates are wild guesses but the coordinates relative to the world could be(100,740)

Comment: hmm... someone deleted his comment :D

Comment: Depending on how your camera is defined, can't you just add the offset of the camera? e.g. `shipPos = new Vector2(ms.X, ms.Y) + camera.TopLeftCorner;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) 
{
    Vector2 shipPos = new Vector2(
                      ms.X-screenWidth/2 + previousShipPosition.X,
                      ms.Y-screenHeight/2 + previousShipPosition.Y
                      );
}
```